# How to set collection view cell without gap between two cell in single row

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I placed one collection view with one custom cell using storyboard.Totally i have 6 images so per row i have 2 images ( 2 cell).Now when i run the gap between 2 cells is much more.i need to remove all gap between all cells so how it should look like is without gap having 6 images .Now below image is what i need to remove gap [image]

I try to increase the width of cell using story board. But i doesn't work. Is there any idea to get with out gap between each cell in all rows ( right, top, bottom gap between all cells )

Please help me out.Thanks

But when i run in iphone 6, i am getting like this , why??
[image]

Comment: Open your storyboard->select your collection view->click on size inspector ->adjust minimum space between items to 0, adjust minimum space between rows to 0

Comment: i have to select my collection view cell or whole collection view

Comment: You need to set the item size in your layout so that the cells width is equal to half of the screen width

Comment: i did, but only top and bottom cell are showing without gap.. How about lefte and right side of cell??

Comment: @dan can you explain in brief, ??. Where i can set the size for my layout?

Comment: @dan please see my update post.. While run in iphone 6 all cell are having this much gap,,But for iphone 5s its working without gap

Comment: Assuming you are using a `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` then it has an `itemSize` property that you can set.  You need to set it in code and not in the storyboard because it needs a different value based on the screen width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your class conform to UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout protocol and implement the methods:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
              layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CGFloat width = self.collectionView.frame.size.width/2;
    return CGSizeMake(width, width);
}


-(UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {

   return UIEdgeInsetsZero;
}

-(CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {

   return 0.0;
}

-(CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
   return 0.0;
}
```

Comment: please see my update post.. While run in iphone 6 all cell are having this much gap,,But for iphone 5s its working without gap

Comment: You see a bigger gap on iPhone 6 because the screen is larger than the iPhone 5s and the size of your cells are probably fixed. You can change the cell size dynamically overriding the method collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath: (described above)

Comment: @ scollaco i need to just add this method 1- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
              layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CGFloat width = self.collectionView.frame.size.width/2;
    return CGSizeMake(width, width);
}` is enough ?

Comment: It will change the size of your cells according to the collectionView size. The other methods will configure the layout to don't allow gaps between the cells.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `minimumInteritemSpacing` in the UICollectionViewFlowLayout, here in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewFlowLayout_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UICollectionViewFlowLayout/minimumInteritemSpacing) you can see more details

Like this,

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
flowLayout.minimumInterItemSpacing = 1;

self.collectionView.layout = flowLayout;
```

Source : http://nsscreencast.com/episodes/46-fun-with-uicollectionview

Comment: This is only setting a minimum spacing, not a maximum spacing. It will not prevent the gaps between the cells.